# nested column() widget confusion/unknown result in dart/flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, frontend

Both the codes that is presented here works fine but I am unable to understand what is going on .

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,

        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Click Counter'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [Text("hello")],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This has the output where the whole vertical height is taken by`column()`widget which has a red background at back which is the color of the container. Here my understanding is  that since the `mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.max` is the default property of `column()` so it took the 100% of the vertical axis space with width of that of its `child` . But for this portion of code:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,

        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Click Counter'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(  
         
          children: [Text("parent column"),
          Container(
            color:Colors.blue,
            child: const Column(children: [Text("child column ")]),)],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is the output 2:here is the parent `column()` taking the whole vertical height 100% but the inner `column()` hasn't been doing so and the blue color is only around its text and it doesnot take 100% height(you will understand clearly once you run both codes).The inner `Column()` has been taking the empty space only to wrap its only child as if the `mainAxisSize`  property has been set to minimum for the inside column. Why is this behavioir ovserved?

So why are there two behaviour of column here though the `mainAxisSize` property is set to `MainAxisSize.max` for both by default but still the character they show is different. Do explain in detail I would love to read all of your comments.

Answer (score 0):

A column can take all the space it is given, and in return offers all the mainAxis space to its children.  If you nest those directly, you get the dreaded "infinite inside infinite" error.  One quick solution is to wrap the inner column with an Expanded, which will limit the inner space to only whatever is available.

Edit: anything within the inner column must also conform to the infinite space.  In my testing, I ended up with `Column > Expanded > Column > Expanded > Placeholder`, which seemed to conform just fine.

Comment: yeah I was also expecting the same kind of error but fortunately there was no error but a different result for both codes. I couldnt add the images here so it might be difficult to visualize the output. you can once test the codes.